# Google Places Autocomplete API

Tags: api, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Is there a way to use google's autocomplete api for `street_address`?

because when I searched this address using autocomplete

> 51 north 2550 east, spanish fork, UT 84660

it doesn't show up because its type was `street_address`. Is there a way to configure autocomplete api to include street addresses?

Comment: Try to input '51 north 2550 east, spanish fork, UT 84660' if it doesn't show up, maybe its not yet recorded in google.

Comment: it shows up in `Google Places Search API` but not in `Google Places Autocomplete API`

Comment: I can see that places text search can find even two place IDs for this address: ChIJn3fMVV68TYcRbnJJvVmVDXY and ChIJTVhGYl68TYcRyPEl4S0IzEU. Both have street_address type. To my knowledge the place autocomplete should include street addresses by default. Even when I add filter `&types=address` and bias results to Spanish Fork I still have zero results in autocomplete. This sounds like a bug, I would suggest filing it in [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=787713).